# I need Create a VF page and controller to allow user to create 5 contacts

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need Create a VF page and controller to allow user to create 5 contacts (as soon as user land on page, show 5 empty contact rows where user can input) for given account ID in url and save them to that account. Also allow user to add more contaact rows if needed using a button.

Comment: What you have tried ? Where you got struck ?

Comment: i have no idea how to create five empty rows

Comment: You should look at this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_inline_editing.htm) and see how you can setup VF page with inline editing. Second, you need to implement a `controllerExtension` (class) that would process the account id and save the contacts to Salesforce. Once done with the above suggestion, paste your code, if you have face issue by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code and Modify it as per your requirement.

VF Page :

```
<apex:page showChat="false" wizard="true" sidebar="false" standardController="Account" extensions="MemberController">
  <!-- Javascript -->
 <script type = "text/javascript">
   function winClose()
    {
    self.close();
    }
 </script>
<!-- End of Javascript-->
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock id="membAdd" >   
<apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}"  />               
    <apex:pageblockSection columns="1">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!memberAddList}" var="memb" >
            <apex:facet name="footer">
                <apex:commandLink value="Add Row" action="{!addRow}" reRender="membAdd"/>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:column headerValue="No." style="width:20px; text-align:center;" headerClass="centertext">
                <apex:outputText value="{0,number, ###}" style="text-align:center;">   
                    <apex:param value="{!rowNum+1}" />   
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>            
            <apex:column headerValue="Member First Name">
                <apex:inputField value="{!memb.FirstName}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Member Last Name">
                <apex:inputField value="{!memb.LastName}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Email Id">
                <apex:inputField value="{!memb.Email}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Delete" >
                <apex:commandLink style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;color:red;" value="X" action="{!delRow}" reRender="membAdd,temp" rendered="{!rowNum>0}">
                    <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="index" />
                </apex:commandLink>
                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
            </apex:column>                
        </apex:pageBlockTable>                    
    </apex:pageblockSection>        
    <apex:pageblockSection columns="1" >
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveMemb}" onComplete="winClose();"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="winClose();" />
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>         
    </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class MemberController
{
public List<Contact> memberAddList {get;set;}
public String memberName {get;set;}
public Integer rowNum{get;set;}
List<Contact> updateContList = new List<Contact>();
Account acc;

public MemberController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.acc= (Account)controller.getRecord();
    memberAddList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<5;i++)
    memberAddList.add(new Contact());
}

public void AddRow()
{
    memberAddList.add(new Contact());
}

public void delRow()
{
    rowNum = Integer.valueOf(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('index'));
    memberAddList.remove(rowNum);   
}    

public void saveMemb()
{
    for(Contact m: memberAddList )
    {
      m.AccountId=acc.id;
      updateContList.add(m);
    }
    insert updateContList ;
}
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you improve your answer by adding standard controller "Account" and while saving attach the contact to the account.

Comment: @user51022 If it solved your problem, please mark it as solution so it helps to other.

Comment: here we didnot pass any id as url.i need the id to pass as url.can u check it once

Comment: @user51022 I didn't get your point. I've given you whole idea, you can do small changes as per requirement.

Comment: ok thankyou so much its working